# Overlapping div box like google keep

Tags: css

How do you make overlapping div box like google keep.

[image]

Any answer will be highly appreciated! 
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by overlapping div? Please be more specific.

Comment: arranging box of div depends on height of another div above

Answer (score 0):

check this codepen

```
https://codepen.io/rahulkapoor/pen/uAhzx
```

also bootstrap 4 has class **card columns**  which might help you achieve what you want

```
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#Cardcolumns
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the page into a grid, and fill up each column with the divs. You can use css [floats](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) or html [tables](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp) to achieve the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The best (and most backwards-compatible) way to do this would be to create a series of `div`s that are next to each other horizontally. They would be created in JavaScript, and each of them would have an equal width so they add up to 100% of the width of their container. For example:

```
for(i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) { 
    var column = $("<div class='column'></div>");
    column.css("width", (100 / numColumns) + "px");
    $("#column-container-id-here").append(column);
}
```

The class `column` would have to be defined in a stylesheet to have a `display` attribute of `inline-block` so that all of the `div`s will act like columns. Then, inside of each of the `column` divs you can can have your cards (which would also be `div`s) and they will automatically stack vertically.